# for each always returns the same item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, c#-3.0

I have a website and when you order 2 products they are added in the database so know i have this model

```
    public IQueryable<CommonLayer.Models.OrdersModel> GetOrderAsModel(Guid id)
    {
        return (from p
                in this.Entities.ORDERS
                join orderdetails in this.Entities.ORDERDETAILS on p.OrderId equals orderdetails.OrderDetailsOrderId
                where p.OrderId == id
                select new CommonLayer.Models.OrdersModel()
                {
                    Orderid = p.OrderId,
                    Orderdetailsid = orderdetails.OrderDetailsOrderId,
                    OrderDate = p.OrderDate,
                    Orderstatus = p.OrderStatus,
                    ProductQty = orderdetails.ProductQuantity,
                    OrderNum = p.OrderNum,
                    Userid = p.UserId,
                    ProductName = orderdetails.PRODUCT.ProductName
                });
    }

   This model return the order along with the order details(if for example i have two products i have two orderdetails)
```

Now i am trying to add the ability to alter the value of some fields from an order and i am trying to get all products in a specific order, if i have for example 4 products it returns for but they are all exactly like the first product entered even if i have different products, even the quantity if in the order i have 1 of one product and 5 of the other it returns two products same name same quantity. Below code shows the for each i am trying to implement:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
             <div class="form-group">
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>

            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ProductQty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ProductQty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. Use a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Replace `model.FirstOrDefault()`with just `item`

Comment: How would i implement the for loop ? and i never used an EditorTemplate , this is my first time using mvc

Comment: @CodeNotFound, That will not work. The values will not post back and bind to the model. You MUST use a `for` loop of custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Ha indeed @StephenMuecke you are right. Hope he will go to check the link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable

Comment: CodeNotFound i get this error now, but i have a paramter of type int ProductQty in the controller The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ProductQty' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(System.Guid, System.String, Int32)'

Comment: @Alessandro, That is an entirely different issue and has no relationship to the code you have shown. It self explanatory (you have not provided values for the 2nd method), but if you can work it out then ask a new question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i checked that link, in order to use the for in my case how would i implement that ?

Comment: As per the link! - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].ProductName) ..... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i get a red line under Model.Count and also on m => m[i].ProductName)

Comment: Then make the model `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` or use an `EditorTemplate` as per the link - Please read the dupe carefully.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i never did such  thing of the editortemplate and i am not understanding what the person is saying in the link

Comment: That person is me :) And in your case your need to create an `EditorTemplate` named `/View/Shared/EditorTemplates/OrdersModel.cshtml. where the model is `@model OrdersModel` and in the main view its `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)`

Comment: i don't have editortemplate file ? should i create it ?

Comment: this is too difficult to understand is there any other way ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i try to change the iqueryable to IList<T> it gives me an error under the select command

Comment: It says  iqueryable cannot be converted to List

Comment: Oh dear - just add `.ToList()` after your query - `(from p( .... select new CommonLayer.Models.OrdersModel(){ .... }).ToList();`

Comment: that works, but the quantity won't get posted now on submit for multiple products not even for one product where before if i had one product in order it would be changed.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by you last comment. If you have another issue, ask a new question and show the relevant code